# Bash special character used in YAML file

Tags: bash, yaml, travis-ci

I am struggling with some bash script that generates some Environment Variables for me. I am using it in **.travis.yml** file later.

My encrypted key looks like that:

`someRandomCharacters
withNewLine`

In Terminal I checked three possibilities.

```
echo "someRandomCharacters
withNewLine" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:SomePassword -base64 -d
```

and

```
echo "someRandomCharacters\nWithNewLine" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:SomePassword -base64 -d
```

will give me correct output.

```
echo "someRandomCharactersWithNewLine" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:SomePassword -base64 -d
```

This one above will return `error reading input file`

So far so good - I understand why it works like that. But when  I try to enter any of abovementioned options - for example like that:

```
 - SOME_ENV=`echo "someRandomCharacters\nWithNewLines" | openssl enc -aes 128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:SomePassword -base64  -d`
```

into ***travis.yml***, two **last** options will return `error reading input file` and the first one will crash the whole build due to incorrect *.yaml* syntax.

I've tried to use any of these three above + many more for example with ***"\n"*** as special character as I found in examples here on STO. Any of them would return `error reading input file` and none of them returned me decrypted `SOME_ENV` into travis. Is there any solution for that? Or maybe my poor experience with BASH and YAML blocks me for seeing obvious mistake?

Comment: All of your commands will always print "error reading input file". You're posting invalid data and asking why your data is invalid. This makes it hard to reason about. Please consider making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, you can use  `U2FsdGVkX1821xiZpgtUK7OIbGrHzGCPbN+bJ1WYKmg=` and put your linefeed anywhere, which given your fake password will decode successfully to "My data". I'm guessing it's because `dash` expands `\n` while `bash` does not, but your fabricated examples are inconsistent because `openssl` does not require linefeeds in the middle of b64 data.

Comment: Could You please explain what do You mean that all my command will always print this error?
What do You mean that my fabricated examples are inconsistent? I was checking that side to side with my real values and outputs in Terminal, and I'm certainly sure that examples are relevant. I would provide screenshot, but that would miss the point.

Comment: I mean that if you copy-paste the commands from your post into a terminal, it will fail (because it doesn't contain real values). Don't run "side to side with your real values", generate values that you are comfortable sharing, and then post those. For example, this is a command that you can copy-paste directly into a terminal: `echo "U2FsdGVkX19EB+D8no9+9bnl4dE5H2WbOUSvsGZjK7s=" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:MyPassword -base64 -d`

Comment: I will start by making MCVE, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While it's hard to tell what exactly the problem is given fake data, here are some data points:

`dash` (the shell you get if you just run `sh` on modern Linux distros) and `bash` behave differently in certain cases.

You should never assume that a code snippet runs with `bash`, because any number of reasons can cause it to be run with `sh` instead, and it's sometimes hard to tell.

Here's a script containing a `\n` sequence that works with `sh` but fails with `bash`:

```
$ cat myfile
echo "U2FsdGVkX19EB+D8no\n9+9bnl4dE5H2WbOUSvsGZjK7s=" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:MyPassword -base64 -d

$ sh myfile
My test data

$ bash myfile
error reading input file
```

If we instead use `echo -e`, we get the opposite result where `dash` fails and `bash` works:

```
$ cat myfile
echo -e "U2FsdGVkX19EB+D8no\n9+9bnl4dE5H2WbOUSvsGZjK7s=" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:MyPassword -base64 -d

$ sh myfile 
error reading input file

$ bash myfile
My test data
```

This is why POSIX recommends not using `echo`. If we instead use `printf`, it works on both:

```
$ cat myfile
printf "U2FsdGVkX19EB+D8no\n9+9bnl4dE5H2WbOUSvsGZjK7s=\n" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:MyPassword -base64 -d

$ sh myfile
My test data

$ bash myfile
My test data
```

However, the line feed sequence in the middle is optional for `openssl`, and can just be removed (even though you seem to say that this doesn't work: maybe you removed the `\` but not the `n`?)

```
$ cat myfile 
echo "U2FsdGVkX19EB+D8no9+9bnl4dE5H2WbOUSvsGZjK7s=" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:MyPassword -base64 -d

$ sh myfile
My test data

$ bash myfile
My test data
```